# UIImagePickerController the take photo button not work, until long press or click many times

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I just want to take a picture from camera through my app. But present to the UIImagePickerController, the take photo button does't work, i can see the button is pressed style up and down.But no photo is captured.Until i long press the take button or click many times, then a photo can be captured.

in my project, the current UIViewController obey the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and UINavigationControllerDelege. But it still does'n make a difference.

the code like this below:

`UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];`

I try add the code:

```
picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

it does'n work neither.

Please help me. I search for solutions many times all around, but no one can solve my problem.
Thanks!

Comment: I had the same situation before, when I was using FaceBook or WeChat to take a picture and the process was so slowly. But after that, I restart my phone to solve this problem. Sometimes it seems the iPhone's memory is running out.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But it still doesn't work. In every UIViewController of my app project, only if i invoke these codes above in any UIViewController, the same result will appear. So i check the info.plist, but it seems it doesn't have errors. I still can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question took me much time on it, but i still could not solve after debug many times. So i finally decided to custom the camera. I found a wonderful code in github website, the link is [here](https://github.com/tdginternet/TGCameraViewController)

anyone interested can have a look.

Finally, i found another similar scene: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/232522#232522